# Missing data - MI decreasing R-squared

Tags: multiple-imputation

I have quite a bit of missing data (7-10%), however this is due to individuals running out of time to complete the questionnaire and so it is missing at random (the order of the questions was random, so there is a fairly even split of missingness across the questions).

I have attempted to use multiple imputation using the Gelman mi package in R - however the resulting data significantly decreased the R-squared for my regression model (.27 to .165).

I have limited time before my thesis is due and so am therefore planning on using listwise deletion. However, in terms of writing up my method / results section, I was wondering if anyone can help explain why the MI may have resulted in such an increase in variance?

Comment: I would heavily question the missing at random assumption: you are making the assumption that taking longer to complete the questionnaire is independent of the answers to the questionnaire. Especially given your results, I would wonder if failing to complete the questionnaire in the given amount of time was indicative of a different trend.

Comment: You use missing data methods because you think they will give different results. You shouldn't be surprised you're getting different results - but you're not giving us much information. Are the parameter estimates changing? Are the variances changing?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying to my question. Cliff you make a good point my assumption that the data is MAR. The parameter estimates are not changing considerably, but the variance has increased. My understanding is that if the imputed missing data changes the nature of the relationships within your data, that the data imputed isn't valid?